# htaccess predefined rules hostagator

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In hostagator , I must use some predefined htaccess rules , like below to set my main dir for domain .

```
#Change example.com to be your main domain.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$*

#Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/*

#Don't change these line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d*

#Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1*
```

---

Now problem here that when I type in my browser :
example.com/some_dir  (without trailing slash)
It will show urls like example.com/subdir/some_dir/ , which I like to be example.com/some_dir/*

but I can't change any of above predefined rules , otherwise it ruins my site because it must to have for my dir structure . and so the adding traling slash rule is also not working .

my dir structure is like this :

/

/subdir/.htaccess

/subdir/index.php

/subdir/some_dir

/subdir/some_other_dir

etc

---

Or any other way to redirect fully example.com/some_dir to example.com/some_dir/ for new request , so that those above rules be follwed after new request .?

---

**Partially Solved:**

I found somewhere on stackoverflow for adding trailing backslash:
    RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9-]+/)*[a-z0-9-]+)$ $1/

so just by using that I tried making rules like this, and put before my above predefined rules :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/
```

And Now it is working without trailing slash
For example 
example.com/some_dir , is not going redirected to example.com/subdir/some_dir/ but working just staying at example.com/some_dir (without trailing slash) ..

Can anyone explain what this regex (([a-z0-9-]+/)*[a-z0-9-]+) means ? and how it is working ?

and now example.com/some_dir/dir1 is having same problem as my main question  , How can i modify above rule for this ?

Comment: So ¿What's exactly your question? Try to be as clear as possible and add some examples. There have to be some `patterns` for somebody to be able to provide a useful answer.

Comment: problem here that when I type in my browser : 
example.com/some_dir (without trailing slash) 
It will show urls like example.com/subdir/some_dir/ 
which I want to be like example.com/some_dir/ ,

Comment: All you have to do is remove the rewrite rule at the end of the file. Be aware that modifying the URLs mapping that way might have an impact on performance or a lot of 404 errors.

Comment: No , that's not gonna work , and cause lots of 404 , because as I have told its mandatory to work my site .

Comment: Then, any rule that you have in a lower sub-directory to modify those rules, will have priority over them and the result will be the same: Problems. Try asking Hostgator to modify those rules and explain to them the problem.

Comment: Any way to redirect for new request from 
example.com/some_dir 
to 
example.com/some_dir/
so all rules processed again . because example.com/some_dir/ showing properly .

Comment: It is possible, of course, but there will be conflicting rules. I would not recommend such a solution, you will have many problems.